# How does one modify the tabs of visual studio through the VS SDK?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I am wondering what i need to do in order to modify the tabs of visual studio similar to tabsstudio. 50$ seems too expensive for me for an addon which does so little. So i'm wondering what's necessary in order to get access to the tabs.

So far it seems that useful resources are:

[IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

In order to get access to the tabs i've tried creating a margin and recurse to the potential tabscontrol to get started. Unfortunately i was unable to traverse upwards to that tabscontrol. I tried `VisualTreeHelper`, `LogicalTreeHelper` and `.Parent` in order to get there - past the WpfTextViewHost none of my calls returned the desired object.

I have used this method in order to attempt traversal:

```
private IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetParentsRecursive(DependencyObject element)
{
    var current = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(element) ?? VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) ?? (element is FrameworkElement f && f.Parent != null ? f.Parent : null);
        if(current == null)
        yield break;
    yield return current;
    foreach (var parent in GetParentsRecursive(current))
    {
        yield return parent;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions in order to get started writing an addon for this?

[image: Margin drawing to the editor]

Update: Lots of reflection makes it appear like the types needed to do what i am trying are not within the VS sdk, but within references for VS itself. More updates to come i guess.

Comment: Did you ever have any success in this? I too am trying to create a plugin for VS2017, but after much reading it seems that tabs aren't catered for in the SDK.

Comment: @MSOACC i have not found a way which isn't utterly disgusting no. seems like the VS shell developers really don't want the SDK to provide an interface to modify tabs sadly

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have you used TabStudio? It has a free trial and offers a very nice implementation of tabs. However, if you remove it from the toolbar it completely kills the tabs, so I suspect what they have is some complicated replication of tabs, rather than actually modifying the tabs themselves.

Comment: @MSOACC I did actually. For me it just wasn't worth the money which is why i tried to get it done myself. And yeah - i am pretty sure there are quite a few tricks involved for that extension. All an extension developer would really want is getting access to the tab headers to merge them :/

Comment: I contacted the developer of TabStudio and he said the following: "Yes, I used the SDK. Plus some additional access to internal Visual Studio objects". I imagine there's a reason he's charging so much for it.

Comment: @MSOACC interesting to know. From a cost value aspect it's still super expensive compared to other extensions though